# HBase pre-splitting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I want to pre-split HBase table for e.g. on 5 regions like this `hbase(main):001:0> create 'table','info',SPLITS => ['1000','2000','3000','4000']`

If one of the regions (e.g., the region is 1000 ~ 2000) meets the split conditions and has been split(Assume that before the split is called region1, after the split is called region2). Now there is data with rowkey 1001 written, so which region will it be written to, region1 or region2?

I know that without pre-splitting the data will be written to the new region when a split occurs but is this also the case with pre-splitting?

The reason I have this problem is that when a pre-splitting is done and then a split occurs, the regions become extra. I originally wrote only a few pre-specified regions, so how is the extra region handled?

Answer (score 0):

To identify which region holds the key after a region split, You need to check the start and end key of the region. The key which falls under the start and end key will be available from that region.

`echo "list_regions 'table'" | hbase shell -n`

When a region ungoes a split, it will create 2 new regions and close the old region once the new regions are active. The region with new splits will have a new region name.

```
echo "split 'table', '500'" | hbase shell -n 
echo "list_regions 'table'" | hbase shell -n
```